# Configuring self hosted wcf service endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've taken the most basic example of setting up a hosted endpoint ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx ... and from this i want to have my service be configured in the way that it does within say IIS ... using the config file for my application.

That seemingly is not the default in this scenario.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

as per the link above i have something like this ...

```
// Create the ServiceHost.
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
{
    // Enable metadata publishing.
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
    // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
    // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
    // by the service.
    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Close the ServiceHost.
    host.Close();
}
```

now i want to have the "baseAddress" and the smb object info assigned using config. 
for example as defined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx ...

```
<system.ServiceModel>

   <services>
   <!—- Define the service endpoints. This section is optional in the new
    default configuration model in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service>
         <endpoint/>
      </service>
   </services>

   <bindings>
   <!-- Specify one or more of the system-provided binding elements,
    for example, <basicHttpBinding> --> 
   <!-- Alternatively, <customBinding> elements. -->
      <binding>
      <!-- For example, a <BasicHttpBinding> element. -->
      </binding>
   </bindings>

   <behaviors>
   <!-- One or more of the system-provided or custom behavior elements. -->
      <behavior>
      <!-- For example, a <throttling> element. -->
      </behavior>
   </behaviors>

</system.ServiceModel>
```

my problem is that if i browse to the configured base address using my browser the endpoint isn't there as expected.

I get no errors and its acting like theres an active endpoint up ... but where is it?

EDIT 2: Additional info:
The code i'm using is as above, my config file looks like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    <section name="TaskServiceConfiguration" type="emedia.nemo.Configuration.XmlSerializerSectionHandler, emedia.nemo"/>
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <TaskServiceConfiguration type="Emedia.TaskScheduler.Service.TaskServiceConfiguration, Emedia.TaskScheduler.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <PollInterval>5</PollInterval>
    <ServiceURL>http://localhost:10000/TaskSchedulerService.svc</ServiceURL>
  </TaskServiceConfiguration>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="log-file.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="DebugFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="log-file.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <foreColor value="Red"/>
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <foreColor value="Yellow"/>
      </mapping>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5level- %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Default" type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" />
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" propagateActivity="true" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Default" type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" />
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener"
           initializeData="Web_messages.svclog"
           traceOutputOptions="Timestamp"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
           />
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"
           initializeData="Web_tracelog.svclog"
           traceOutputOptions="Timestamp"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
           />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- Server side stuff -->
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpBehaviour"
               name="Emedia.Messaging.Services.TaskSchedulerService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:10000/TaskSchedulerService.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Emedia.Messaging.Services.ITaskServiceContract"
                  />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wsHttpBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

    <!-- Client side stuff -->
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 transactionFlow="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                 allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                        maxStringContentLength="8192"
                        maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384"
                        />
          <reliableSession ordered="true"
                           inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                           enabled="false"
                           />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
                       proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm=""
                       />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
                     negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                     algorithmSuite="Default"
                     />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:10000/TaskSchedulerService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="WCFTask.ITaskServiceContract"
                name="wsHttpBinding">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: some more detail on scope:

the wcf endpoint is defined in a web project.
the web project is referrenced by a windows service which hosts an instance of it. 
i then have a console app that refers to and creates an instance of the windows service in order to test it.

My question is about getting that console app to fire up the windows service and that in turn the WCF endpoint so that it can then make calls on the endpoint in order to perform some end to end testing of my solution.

Comment: What **exactly** is your question?? Can you show us some code and/or config that you have and describe what problems / issues you have??

Comment: ok ... 1 min il add some detail

Comment: If you are hosting in IIS then on your server side stuff of the endpoint element just leave the address attributes value to empty as the address is taken care by IIS and then that should get it working

Comment: im hosting the WCf endpoint in a console app

Comment: @Wardy - see my revised answer.  I still think you're getting service and client mixed up.  Unless you're trying to use the console app to test the logic of your windows service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revised Answer Based On Additional Info**

Ok, if I understand you correctly, you've created a WCF web application, and a separate Windows Service that creates an instance of that WCF service.  Now you're trying to create a console app to test your solution.

I think you're making things more complex than they need to be.  The Windows Service should either be a client that calls the WCF service, or it should host the WCF service itself.

In either event, if you're writing a console app to do end-to-end testing of your solution, it certainly seems to me that the console app is the *client* - which as I've said has nothing to do with `ServiceHost` or hosting the service.

Simply start the service from within your console app (or start it separately and have it already running), and then execute calls against the Windows Service in the same way any other client would.

If I'm still missing something, let me know and I'll try again. I'm about to sign off, so feel free to e-mail me (my address is in my profile) and I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: that's my problem ... i've added the app.config file and configured the service but it's like it's ignoring the config file and just acting like i'm doing this without it being there

Comment: Ah..didn't catch that part.  Is the service running when you go to it in the browser?

Comment: if i do ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService)) then the browser cant find it but if i do ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), "http://localhost:10000/TaskSchedulerService.svc")) then it can but it then informs me that metadata publishing is not enabled

Comment: Do you have a .svc page?  I've only used them (and seen them used) for IIS-hosted WCF services.

Comment: ok the svc is defined in a web project, i then have a ref to that project that the console app uses to create the service host and fire up the endpoint (as seen above) i then add a "service ref" to the project which give me the generated proxy classes ect and config info for connecting to the service.

Comment: after firing up the servicehost instance i would expect to be able to create an instance of the ServiceClient and call methods on it in the normal WCF manner ... the problem i have here is that WCF does not appear to be doing what i am accostomed to in IIS with a separate console app bound to it

Comment: Why are you bothering with the web project and the service file?  Are you trying to create a console app for the client, or a console app to host the service?  It *seems* like you're trying to use the console app as a client, in which case you don't need to do anything with `ServiceHost`, as the web project will instantiate the `ServiceHost`.

Comment: its a bit more complex than i have explained ... the web project contains the wcf services for mosto f the business, the console app is a wrapper around a windows service, this particular windows service needs to persist some objects between calls, something that the stateless nature of a web app can't do when there are no calls on it for long periods of time. The WCF endpoint is referred to by the windows service and hosted within it, the console app fires up an instance of the windows service to test calls to the wcf endpoint on it.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to take an existing service's endpoint and host it in a different ServiceHost, and I don't think that will work (and it seems more complex than it needs to be).  If you need to persist data between calls and don't want to use session mode (or store the data in something like a database), a windows service is a good way to go (as it can be always on, as long as the server is up), but it seems like you're trying to make a hybrid IIS/Windows Service hosted service - which is most likely not possible.

Comment: If the console app is simply to test that the Windows Service is there and make calls against it, then the console app is the *client*, and has no need to do anything with ServiceHost.  The Windows Service will handle that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10037/discussion-between-wardy-and-tim) ..... or not ... company proxy server prevents it

Comment: you are correct that's exactly what i'm trying to do, I am trying to fire up the windows service (which hosts my WCF endpoint) in the console app. The windows service however talks to the endpoint it hosts (business requirement don't ask)

Comment: So the problem then is that the Windows Service is not able to access the endpoint?

Comment: yes ... but i thought about what you said and im going to talk directly to the business service that sits behind the WCF endpoint from within the windows service thus the windows service will now perform only 1 function ... hosting the WCF endpoint

Comment: im fortunate enough that this is a welll structured n-tier stack and that the WCf endpoint only "passes calls on to the business" rather than actually providing a any service as such ... the WCF endpoint is about making the business service highly available and by hosting it in this manner i can be sure that long running tasks are tracked and managed as appropriate.